# Cannot find protocol declaration NSObject

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, uinavigationcontroller, protocols

I am about to try and pass a value that the suer selectes in a subview back to the mainview of my application. I have been doing abit of reading about how to do it, and am currently following a fairly informative tutorial [here](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/04/15/passing-data-between-views-tutorial-using-a-protocol-delegate-in-your-iphone-app/)

I am starting from step 18 and implementing this into my code as it seems fairly straight forward... however I have this error in my secondview.h file where I am declaring my protocol as follows.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol PassSearchData <nsobject> //this is where I get the "Cannot find protocol declaraton for 'nsobject' error
@required
- (void) setSecondFavoriteColor:(NSString *)secondFavoriteColor;
@end


@interface VehicleResultViewController : UITableViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate> {
//...
//Delegate stuff for passing information back to parent view
    id <PassSearchData> delegate;

}
//..
//Delegate stuff for passing information back to parent view
@property (retain) id delegate;
//..
@end
</PassSearchData></nsobject></uikit/uikit.h> //more errors here also..
```

Comment: NSObject is case sensitive, so you want PassSearchData <NSObject>

Comment: rightyho, lol thankyou should have spotted that myself. thanks :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Malcolm Box mentioned in the comment, `NSObject` (and most source code, for that matter) is case-sensitive. Also, I'm not sure what the last line with `</PassSearchData></nsobject></uikit/ uikit.h>` is supposed to be. I'd suggest something like the following:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol PassSearchData <NSObject>
@required
- (void) setSecondFavoriteColor:(NSString *)secondFavoriteColor;
@end


@interface VehicleResultViewController : UITableViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate> {
//...
//Delegate stuff for passing information back to parent view
    id <PassSearchData> delegate;

}
//..
//Delegate stuff for passing information back to parent view
@property (assign) id <PassSearchData> delegate; // not retain ?
//..
@end
```

That code should probably compile, but that doesn't necessarily mean it's problem-free. Traditionally, delegates are not retained, because of the [problem of retain cycles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-1000810). So I changed the declaration of the `delegate` property from `retain` to `assign`.